# ServiceStack authentication key icon missing

Tags: authentication, servicestack

ServiceStack authentication key icon missing

Answer (score 1):

This is working as expected, tested with the latest version of ServiceStack:

[image]

On a side note this [AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query) Request DTO has a conflict since it [already implements](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/1304873a9ee27e57942e3d97f0bd6edf4e8bae72/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/IQuery.cs#L90) `IReturn<QueryResponse<Order>>`, so you should remove the invalid `IReturn<T>` marker from your DTO so it's just:

```
[Authenticate]
[Route("/Orders")]
public class Orders : QueryBase<Order>, IHasVersion
{
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public Orders() { Version = 1; }
}
```